# PHP error on EE 2.9 with PHP 5.6

Tags: error

After logging out of the front i get this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 7 bytes

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 931
```

PHP: 5.6
EE: 2.9

Comment: I'm getting a handfull of errors with PHP 5.6.1. I use MAMP and bumped the PHP version back to 5.5.17 and they all went away.